# How should I update the data by using List in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Account.java

```
public class Account {
    private String _Phone;
    private String _IC;
    private String _FullName;
    private List<String> _CarPlate;

    public Account(){}

    public Account(String fullname, String phone, List<String> carplate, String IC)
    {
        this._Phone=phone;
        this._CarPlate=carplate;
        this._FullName=fullname;
        this._IC=IC;
    }
       public void set_CarPlate(List<String> CarPlate){this._CarPlate=_CarPlate;}

    public List<String> get_CarPlate(){return _CarPlate;}

    public void set_Phone(String _Phone) {
        this._Phone = _Phone;
    }

    public String get_Phone() {
        return _Phone;
    }

    public String get_IC() {
        return _IC;
    }

    public void set_IC(String _IC){this._IC=_IC;}

    public String get_FullName() {
        return _FullName;
    }

    public void set_FullName(String _FullName){ this._FullName=_FullName;}
```

Based on my understandings,

ChangeEmailPassword.java

```
List<String> names=new ArrayList<>();
 changePhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtPhone = newPhone.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!txtPhone.equals("")) {
                mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Account phoneAcc=new Account();
```

//Retrieve all the data from Firebase
                            Map map=(Map)dataSnapshot.getValue();
//Using Map the data to Account.java for encapsulation by using setter

```
 phoneAcc.set_FullName(map.get("_FullName"));
```

//Create the new List object and add the data into the list which is retrieved from Firebase

```
names.add(map.get("_CarPlate"));
phoneAcc.set_CarPlate(names);
phoneAcc.set_IC(map.get("_IC"));
phoneAcc.set_Phone(txtPhone);
```

//add all the value into the firebase again to overwrite the old data

```
mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(phoneAcc);
```

[image: This is the result]

Why I cannot get the list data?

Another problem when I update the phone number twice, it will give me the result like this:

[image: The first result]

[![The second result][3]][3]

and the result of my console will be this

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270425
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270472
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270520
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270576
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270638
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63270680
                           .
                           .
                           .
```

unstoppable

Comment: There's no link for the *second result*.

Comment: @AL. because my reputation very less so cannot post another result to you second result _Phone will be changed to "3453" and then changed back to first result and unstoppable